# Am not able to debug this Navbar subnav slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPjKEB

Scroll over blog then html then css.

The menu detracts. I have been trying to figure this out for quite some time. It works when I simple add a css rule `display:block` on hover but I want the slide down affect.

Unfortunately it gives that weird bug.

The same bug appears on mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using a lot of unnecessary javascript/jquery code and it is causing confusion in your code. You can accomplish what you are trying with these simple couple lines:

```
$('#nav li').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).find('ul').slideDown(120);
});
$('#nav li').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).find('ul').slideUp(120);
});
```

And you can find the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/e0bLs567/1/